# How to average hourly data over a 2 day period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code for a DB in SQL Server, my only issue is that I have to take the hourly average from the start of 10:00:00AM on day 1 to 09:00:00AM on day 2. I've done this previously for a specific hourly range, but not sure how to do it when the date spans across 2 days.

```
SELECT EFFECTIVEDATETIME AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,


 AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KBOS' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END) AS BOSTON_TEMPERATURE,
 AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KBOS' THEN DewPoint ELSE NULL END) AS BOSTON_DEWPOINT,
 AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KBOS' THEN CloudCover ELSE NULL END) AS BOSTON_CLOUDCOVER,
 AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KPVD' THEN TEMPERATURE ELSE NULL END) AS PROVIDENCE_TEMPERATURE,
 AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KPVD' THEN DewPoint ELSE NULL END) AS PROVIDENCE_DEWPOINT,
 AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KPVD' THEN CloudCover ELSE NULL END) AS PROVIDENCE_CLOUDCOVER

FROM DBO.WeatherHourly 

WHERE EffectiveDateTime >= '2020-01-01' AND DATEPART(day, EffectiveDateTime) BETWEEN 8 AND 23
**--would like to find a way to average hourly data from 10am on day 1 to 9am day 2**
AND WeatherStationId IN ('KBOS', 'KPVD')

GROUP BY EFFECTIVEDATETIME

ORDER BY EFFECTIVEDATETIME
```

Here is an example:

```
EFFECTIVE_DATE  BOSTON_TEMPERATURE
2020-01-08 00:00:00.000 37
2020-01-08 01:00:00.000 36
2020-01-08 02:00:00.000 36
2020-01-08 03:00:00.000 36
2020-01-08 04:00:00.000 36
2020-01-08 05:00:00.000 35
2020-01-08 06:00:00.000 34
2020-01-08 07:00:00.000 35
2020-01-08 08:00:00.000 34
2020-01-08 09:00:00.000 36
2020-01-08 10:00:00.000 38
2020-01-08 11:00:00.000 40
2020-01-08 12:00:00.000 42
2020-01-08 13:00:00.000 43
2020-01-08 14:00:00.000 44
2020-01-08 15:00:00.000 44
2020-01-08 16:00:00.000 42
2020-01-08 17:00:00.000 37
2020-01-08 18:00:00.000 38
2020-01-08 19:00:00.000 37
2020-01-08 20:00:00.000 37
2020-01-08 21:00:00.000 34
2020-01-08 22:00:00.000 32
2020-01-08 23:00:00.000 31
2020-01-09 00:00:00.000 29
2020-01-09 01:00:00.000 28
2020-01-09 02:00:00.000 28
2020-01-09 03:00:00.000 27
2020-01-09 04:00:00.000 26
2020-01-09 05:00:00.000 25
2020-01-09 06:00:00.000 24
2020-01-09 07:00:00.000 23
2020-01-09 08:00:00.000 23
2020-01-09 09:00:00.000 25
2020-01-09 10:00:00.000 26
2020-01-09 11:00:00.000 27
2020-01-09 12:00:00.000 29
2020-01-09 13:00:00.000 31
```

**So I would like to take hourly average from 2020-01-08 10:00:00 to 2020-01-09 09:00:00**
Which in this case would be ~ 33.20
I just used the 2020-01-08 as an example, this query would need to be applied to a much larger time frame.

My desired output would be the following:

```
EFFECTIVEDATE BOSTON_TEMPERATURE
2020-01-08   33.20
2020-01-09   30.75   
this date range is continous... not just those 2 days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select avg(boston_temperature * 1.0)
from t
where effective_date >= '2020-01-08 10:00:00' and
      effective_date < '2020-01-09 10:00:00';
```

For your original query, just subtract 10 hours:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -10, EFFECTIVEDATETIME)) AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,  
       AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KBOS' THEN TEMPERATURE END) AS BOSTON_TEMPERATURE,
       AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KBOS' THEN DewPoint END) AS BOSTON_DEWPOINT,
       AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KBOS' THEN CloudCover END) AS BOSTON_CLOUDCOVER,
       AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KPVD' THEN TEMPERATURE END) AS PROVIDENCE_TEMPERATURE,
       AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KPVD' THEN DewPoint END) AS PROVIDENCE_DEWPOINT,
       AVG(CASE WHEN WEATHERSTATIONID = 'KPVD' THEN CloudCover END) AS PROVIDENCE_CLOUDCOVER
FROM DBO.WeatherHourly
WHERE EffectiveDateTime >= '2020-01-01 10:00:00' AND 
      EffectiveDateTime < '2020-01-02 10:00:00' AND
      WeatherStationId IN ('KBOS', 'KPVD')    
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -10, EFFECTIVEDATETIME))
ORDER BY MIN(EFFECTIVEDATETIME)
```

Comment: yeah, that would work for that specific day, but I'd need this for a much longer period of time. I just put the example of 33.20 to show what the expected value would be for 2020-01-08.

Comment: @EdiLacic . . . Your question then has two questions, but I answered that as well.

Comment: Wouldn't that just return values from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-02?

Comment: @EdiLacic . . . Those are the dates in *your queries*.  You can adjust them as you like.

Comment: That query doesn't return what I was looking for, ty anyways.

Comment: @EdiLacic . . . That is not a helpful comment.  This should be doing *exactly* what your question is asking for.

Comment: I edited my question, perhaps that will clear things up, but your code returns the EFFECTIVEDATE in an hourly format still rather than averaging it up for individual days

Comment: @EdiLacic . . . That is very fixable.  I fixed it.

Comment: @EdiLacic . . . As the OP you can *accept* the answer, by clicking on the check mark by the question.  That is different from upvoting it.